# how to get DomainName where a appengine/python website is hosted

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a appengine webapp where i need to set HTTP Location variable to redirect to another page in the same webapp. For that i need to produce a absolute link. for portability reason i cannot use directly the domain name which i am currently using.

Is it possible to produce the domain name on which the webapp is hosted in the python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I quite fully understand the need to getdomain name. But check out if redirect API provided by google app engine will do the job.
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/redirects.html

Comment: You need to get in case you will be using it in emails. How will you be using relative urls in email?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the webapp framework, the current URL is in `self.request.url`. Various components are broken out in properties of self.request, documented [here](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/#urls).

Answer (score 1):

this question is poorly answered. You need the domain name to generate pages like: robots.txt, sitemap.xml and many many more things which are not relative links. Ive tried using this:

```
 from google.appengine.api.app_identity import get_default_version_hostname
 host = get_default_version_hostname()
```

but... it is not good when you upgrade to your own domain... because I still get the appspot.com name.

Answer (score 0):

If your application uses a [custom domain name](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application), then *get_default_version_hostname()* will return *myapp.appspot.com*, or *1.default.myapp.appspot.com* not *mydomain.com*

To get the domain name in the request, use:

```
hostname = self.request.host
```

According to the [webob docs](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/api/request.html?highlight=host#webob.request.BaseRequest.host):

> returns  'Host name provided in HTTP_HOST, with fall-back to
>   SERVER_NAME'

This won't work inside a cron task or if the client calls *myapp.appspot.com* instead of *mydomain.com*.

See also issue: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11993
get_default_version_hostname() won't work inside  /_ah/start handler on a Managed VM. the workaround is to set:
os.environ['DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME'] = os.environ['GAE_APPENGINE_HOSTNAME']